# ¿Cómo puedo buscar un número o un rango de cualquier campo en cualquier tabla en toda la base de datos?

Tags: sql, busqueda, find

Me enfrento a bases de datos desconocidas y a veces solo tengo un dato en la pantalla de una aplicación, pero no sé en qué tabla se encuentra ni en qué campo buscarlo. ¿Cómo podría saberlo?

He visto una pregunta similar en este foro pero es para buscar textos y obliga a crear un procedimiento almacenado. Preferiría una consulta que no tuviese que grabar nada permanente en la base de datos de un cliente (aunque luego pueda borrar el procedimiento).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar por ejemplo:

```
select * from NombreTabla where Id = 100
```

y si quieres un rango más definido con el `between` obtienes un rango de busqueda

```
select * from NombreTabla order by Id between 50 and 99
```

Comment: Hola Luis, tal vez no me expliqué lo suficiente, pero el problema es que no conozco la tabla ni el campo en el que se puede encontrar el número. Solo tengo una base de datos con muchas tablas, algunas con muchos campos, y solo sé que en pantalla en una casilla me aparece por ejemplo el número 1225 y quiero localizarlo.

Answer (score 0):

He dado con una solución a partir de otra consulta en el foro en la que Ariel Octavio D'Alfeo da una muy buena respuesta para encontrar una cadena de texto. He hecho algunas modificaciones para hacer una búsqueda similar para valores numéricos.

```
DECLARE @ValorBusqueda float = 1000
DECLARE @ToleranciaInferior float = 0
DECLARE @ToleranciaSuperior float = 0


CREATE TABLE #Resultado (NombreColumna nvarchar(370), ValorColumna 
nvarchar(3630))
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @NombreTabla nvarchar(256),
@NombreColumna nvarchar(128),
@ValorBusqueda1 varchar(100),
@ValorBusqueda2 varchar(100)


SET  @NombreTabla = ''
SET @ValorBusqueda1 = CONVERT(varchar(100), @ValorBusqueda -     
@ToleranciaInferior)
SET @ValorBusqueda2 = CONVERT(varchar(100), @ValorBusqueda + 
@ToleranciaSuperior)

PRINT @ValorBusqueda1
PRINT @ValorBusqueda2

WHILE @NombreTabla IS NOT NULL
     BEGIN
     SET @NombreColumna = ''
     SET @NombreTabla =
     (SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
     WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
     AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @NombreTabla
     AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
     OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)), 
     'IsMSShipped') = 0)

     WHILE (@NombreTabla IS NOT NULL) AND (@NombreColumna IS NOT NULL)
         BEGIN
         SET @NombreColumna =
         (SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
         WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@NombreTabla, 2)
         AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@NombreTabla, 1)
         AND DATA_TYPE IN ('int', 'money', 'float', 'smallint', 'Decimal')
         AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @NombreColumna)

         IF @NombreColumna IS NOT NULL
              BEGIN
              INSERT INTO #Resultado
              EXEC
              ('SELECT ''' + @NombreTabla + '.' + @NombreColumna + ''', LEFT(' + 
              @NombreColumna + ', 3630)
              FROM ' + @NombreTabla + ' (NOLOCK) ' + ' WHERE ' + @NombreColumna 
              + ' BETWEEN ' + @ValorBusqueda1 + ' AND ' + @ValorBusqueda2)
              END 
         END
     END
     SELECT NombreColumna, ValorColumna FROM #Resultado

     DROP TABLE #Resultado
```

Para buscar un número exacto cambiar el contenido de la variable @ValorBusqueda
Ejemplo para localizar el número 1225.36:

```
DECLARE @ValorBusqueda float = 1225.36
DECLARE @ToleranciaInferior float = 0
DECLARE @ToleranciaSuperior float = 0
```

Para localizar un número con una tolerancia cambiar el contenido de la variable @ValorBusqueda y el de las variables @ToleranciaSuperior y @ToleranciaInferior, según convenga.
Ejemplo si queremos una tolerancia ±0.5 para el número 1225:

```
DECLARE @ValorBusqueda float = 1225
DECLARE @ToleranciaInferior float = 0.5
DECLARE @ToleranciaSuperior float = 0.5
```

Para localizar todos los números dentro de un rango podemos establecer @ValorBusqueda y @ToleranciaSuperior
Ejemplo para buscar todas las coincidencias entre 1220 y 1225:

```
DECLARE @ValorBusqueda float = 1220
DECLARE @ToleranciaInferior float = 0
DECLARE @ToleranciaSuperior float = 5
```